# Compiling statically libc C code and ASM code

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, ld

I have ASM code:

```
    extern my_func
    extern printf
    extern exit
    global _start
section .data
    ...
section .text
  _start:
    ...
    call printf
    ...
    call my_func
    ...
    call exit
```

and C code:

```
    int my_func(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
```

I'm using fedora on 64-bit machine. I want the executable be 32-bit.
For dynamic linking I do:

```
nasm -f elf32 asm.asm ; this gives me asm.o
gcc -m32 -Wall -c c_code.c ; this gives me c_code.o
ld c_code.o asm.o -melf_i386 -L /usr/lib/ -lc -I /lib/ld-linux.so.2 ; this gives me a.out which runs fine and weights 5601 bytes.
```

What I want to do is link libc statically. I do the following:

```
gcc -o a2.out -m32 -static -m32 asm.o c_code.o
```

And I get error:

```
asm.o: In function `_start':
asm.asm:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.text+0x0):
first defined here       
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then I change _start to main in ASM code and the whole thing links fine! ldd shows "not a dynamic executable". But the file created weights 721067 bytes! I think that it compiles statically a lot of unnecessary code. 
So, my 1st question is:

1) How can I link statically only libc for the required printf and exit functions?

When I try

```
gcc -m32 -o a3.out -lc asm.o c_code.o ; ASM file has main instead of _start
```

I get a file that weights 7406 bytes. ldd shows the same dynamic libraries as for the a.out which weights 5601 bytes.

2) Why is that difference? Looks like some additional code that "connects" _start with main in my code...
3) What is the difference between linking with gcc and ld?

Thanks a lot for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

> 1) How can I link statically only libc for the required printf
>   and exit functions?

Try compiling with `-nostartfiles -static -nostdlib -lc` which will avoid adding crt1.o and crtend.o. But keep in mind that this will disable all Glibc initialization code so some Glibc functions will fail to work.

> 2) Why is that difference? Looks like some additional code
>   that "connects" _start with main in my code...

GCC adds start files (`crt*.o`) which perform initialization. See the many online articles for details (e.g. [this one](https://dev.gentoo.org/~vapier/crt.txt)).

> 3) What is the difference between linking with gcc and ld?

Already answered above but in general you can run `gcc -v` and inspect ld's (or collect2's) arguments.

Comment: Thanks! -nostartfiles reduces the size to 5749 bytes. But ldd still shows libc.so.6 which means libc is still linked dynamically.

Comment: @alexeik Also pass `-nostdlib`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the static part, updated reply.

Comment: yugr, I tried 'gcc -o a3 asm.o c_code.o -nostartfiles -static -nostdlib -lc -m32 ' and I get an error with a lot of "undefined reference to..." messages.

Comment: I did some test and added sin to assembly code. So, now `ld -o a3 asm.o c_code.o /usr/lib/libm.a -lc -melf_i386` does clink libm statically and libc dynamically. But  `ld -o a3 asm.o c_code.o /usr/lib/libm.a /usr/lib/libc.a -melf_i386` fails with an error with a lot of "undefined reference to...". Can it be that libc can not be statically linked ALONE (i.e. without being linked statically with ALL libraries required)?

Comment: Yeah, there seem to be additional dependencies on modern distributions. I tried building with `-nostartfiles -nostdlib -static -lc` but this requires `__gcc_personality_v0` and `_Unwind_Resume` probably because libc wants to print friendly stacktrace on error. You can be optimistic and provide dummy implementations for these functions (which abort i.e. call `_exit` on call), then it'll link fine.

Comment: Oh and also I replaced `exit` with `_exit` to avoid linking in `atexit` machinery.