# ld: link with std c static library

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I compile my c code with `gcc -c -nostdlib -fno-stack-protector <my code> -o <my cobj>`, and I want to use the `std` library functions like `sprintf` `strcmp` and so on.So how can I link my `cobj` files with `std` `c` static library?

My `Makefile` link script is `ld -T $@.ld -o $@.o $^ -L.. -llib --no-check-sections`

ps: I compile with `-nostdlib` option because I don't want the `crt` part of the `std` library, but I want to use the platform-independent functions like `sprintf`,`strcmp`,`random`,`va_list` and so on

Comment: This don't make sense. Why say to gcc don't link with stdlib and then ask how to link the stdlib?

Comment: @Stargateur because I don't want the `crt` part of stdlib

Comment: Why don't you want the c runtime library? Seem like a XY problem.

Comment: you could always get the source code for the functions you want, and build your own static library.

Comment: Add `-lgcc` (possibly also `-lc`) to your link script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile with `-nostartfiles -static -nostdlib -fno-stack-protector -lc` but beware that some parts of libc may have dependencies on pieces from libgcc (`__gcc_personality_v0`, etc.) so you'll most probably have errors during linking.

You can provide your own dummy (or not so dummy) implementations of such functions. Or you could just use different libc implementation which does not depend on libgcc (probably newlib or uClibc).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41564885/compiling-statically-libc-c-code-and-asm-code/41565040) may be relevant.